# How to evaluate$ \int \frac{x^2}{(a+bx)^2} dx $ in a simple way?

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate

$$ \int \frac{x^2}{(a+bx)^2} dx $$

By supposing $ u = a+bx $

We have

$$ \int \frac{x^2}{ u ^2} \frac{ du}{ b } $$

I Already know:
• u substitution
• partial fractions

Expanding the denominator does not helps.

Comment: $ y = a+bx, dy = bdx, x = (y-a)/b, ... 1/b^2 \int \frac{(y-a)^2}{y^2}dy = 1/b^2 \int \frac{y^2-2ya+a^2}{y^2}dy= \int(1-2a/y+a^2/y^2)dy  $

Comment: There is a small mistake, but I think you will understand

Comment: @VladislavKharlamov the coefficient should be $1/b^{\color{red}{3}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution you have done is correct. You just have to perform one more step to reach a good integrable form.

**Hint**:
Rewrite the $x^2$ in the numerator as $(\frac{u-a}{b})^2$ and expand. This will lead you to the solution.

Hover above the box below for more detail in case you donot follow the above hint

> Performing the above will give us $$\int \frac{(u-a)^2}{ u ^2} \frac{ du}{ b^3 }=\int \left(\frac{a^2}{u ^2} -\frac{2a}{u} + 1\right) \frac{du}{b^3}$$ Which can be performed using the known basic simple integration.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The annoying part is the denominator, so try to simplify it by substituting $u = a+bx$.

Comment: so $du = b dx$.

Comment: Also $$ \int \frac{x^2}{ u ^2} \frac{ du}{ b } $$ is left

Comment: What's next ? ?

Comment: @RaviPrakash I have added that as an answer above

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the integrand is $b^{-2}(1-\frac{a}{a+bx})^2$. Expand it, then integrate.